# How to access the current row's data in telerik's grid?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a grid, and say I am in given telerik:GridTemplateColumn (or GridboundColumn?) I want to display the result of 2 other columns, how would I do this?

In asp.net repeater I could do:

<%# Container.DataItem("Col3") %> <%# Container.DataItem("Col4") %>

How would I do this in a telerik grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use very similar syntax.  Inside the `GridTemplateColumn`, you need to make an `ItemTemplate`.  In that, you can put whatever markup you want to be displayed in the column.  For example:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Col3 and 4" UniqueName="TemplateColumn">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Container.DataItem("Col3") %> <%# Container.DataItem("Col4") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

For more information, you can reference the documentation for the various column types: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-column-types.html (you'll need to scroll down a ways to get to the section on `GridTemplateColumn`.

Also, I'm assuming you are using Visual Basic?  Otherwise, I think the syntax would be different.